# three.js dom id of canvas element used for webgl renderer

Tags: dom, canvas, three.js, element

I'd like to get the id of the canvas element automatically created by three.js.

Alternately, I would be equally happy (perhaps more so) with the ability to pass along a preexisting canvas element id during construction.

After researching, I tried this:

```
renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { canvas: my_canvas } );
```

without success (it is from a pretty old build, but was hoping it would work). Perhaps some parameter syntax has changed since 2 years ago?

(my_canvas being the id of the canvas, also tried passing along the context, no luck)

Finally I tried:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('canvas');
```

which returned nothing... that was a puzzler and the proverbial straw that led me to post here.

Any insight appreciated, thanks! (I now have voting rights)

Comment: Use `renderer.domElement` to get the DOM element corresponding to the canvas created by the renderer.

Comment: Also, you can pass a canvas to the WebGLRenderer, see here: http://mrdoob.github.com/three.js/docs/57/#Reference/Renderers/WebGLRenderer => it seems it's what you did, according to the doc (and to the source code) it should work

Answer (score 28, accepted):

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvasID");
renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ canvas: canvas });
```

Answer (score 4):

If you look in the latest release (r57) in three.js/src/renderers/WebGLRenderer.js (at the very top of the file) you can see that you can actually pass a canvas argument to the renderer. If you dont pass one, then one is created for you. You would probably need to post some code that does not work or better yet a jsfiddle so we can take a look at the problem.